# APNS - can't get even one push notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, ad-hoc-distribution

Can somebody tell me if you get push notifications?
I think there is a problem with APNS because yesterday everything worked fantastic, no changes were made and today I can't get even one push notification.

Will be happy to hear you answers.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I get push notifications on my distribution build. Is yours on the sandbox or distribution?

Comment: Did your APNS certificate expire?

Comment: Do you have any tutorial for making the pushnotification work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the problem and now everything works just fine.

The problem was with .pem file.

You can use this url for getting correct pem file:

https://pushio.zendesk.com/entries/21644287-generating-a-pem-file-for-ios